# Matplotlib scatterplot marker type by category

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to assign the shape of the marker in the scatter plot by the category. This is the code I used to plot all markers in round shape

```
ax.scatter(found_devices_df['time'], found_devices_df['label'], c=found_devices_df['label'],
               marker='.', s=np.log(found_devices_df['count'])*1000, alpha=.6)
```

Then I change that into the following code the get the shape by the category

```
ax.scatter(found_devices_df['time'], found_devices_df['label'], c=found_devices_df['label'],
               marker=found_devices_df['label'], s=np.log(found_devices_df['count'])*1000, alpha=.6)
```

but I am getting the following error. Appreciate your input to fix this.

```
'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Comment: `found_devices_df['label']`I think this data is a challenge, so we should check the data first. See the [official reference ](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/marker_reference.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-marker-reference-py) for the rest.

Comment: `marker=found_devices_df['label'].tolist()`?